# Convergence acceleration of a series by using optimal parameters

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence, power-series

One of the ways of [accelerating the convergence of a series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) is by transforming into a faster series using optimal parameters. Examples of this approach can be [found in this paper](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Papers/Published-InPress/TenProblems/accelerate.pdf).  I obtained a generalization of this method to express a series in terms of two more independent variables:

> If $|\frac{x}{x+y}| < 1$. Then,
>
> $$ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_nx^n = \Big(\frac{y}{x+y}\Big)^{r+1}
>  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{x}{x+y}\Big)^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n}
>  {n+r\choose k+r}a_k y^k $$

This expresses a power series in the LHS in terms of two independent variables $y$ and $r$ which in theory can be fine tuned to make the series converge faster.

**Question**: How to choose the optimal $y$ and $r$ so that the RHS converges at its fastest rate?

**Note**: Asked this in MSE but got no replies in a week. Posting it here and deleted it from MSE to avoid duplication.

Comment: the right-hand-side of your equation depends on $a_0$, but the left-hand-side does not, how can that be?